# How can I write a contract for non-financial transactions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I am using azure etehereum consortium blockcahin, As of now I have created a contract using solidity, which deals with transfer of ether from sender account to receiver account, but If I want to store a records which don't have any financial information `

> lets say inventory records where person X gives 2 keyboards to person Y

how can I store this transaction in ethereum blockchain and if this record is stored how can I retrieve this information

Answer (score 1):

These patterns may help you get started with general-purpose storage and retrieval. [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to what I understand from the examples in the link above is that the data is stored in the contract (or we can say contract storage) and not on the blockchain, I am thing of is there any way to store the non financial transaction(i.e. assets transfer) data on blockchain in the same way we store financial transaction(ie. ether transfer)

Comment: When I send any transaction to blockchain it will return me the transaction receipt, by using the receipt I can get the Block and Transaction data, so I wanted to know that the "same thing is possible for non financial transaction??? (ie. where I dont transfer ethers)"

Comment: I have deployed the first contract on my ethereum network **Simple List Using Array** while trying access the methods new entity And getEntityCount it always returns zero, bellow is how I tried to access it.

   ` **var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
    function getCount(){
  
  contract.getEntityCount.call(function (error, result){ 
    if(!error){
     alert("count "+result);
    } else{
     alert("Failed");
     console.log(error);
    }
  }); 
 }**
 `
 function putData(){ 
can you tell me where I am going wrong